# Usage of ‘tremendous’

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage

For example

> We have a tremendous amount of work to get through.

Then can I say

> We have tremendous work to get through.

What’s the difference between them?

Comment: Also you changed the object noun in your examples. First it's "amount", then it's "work", which does not necessarily mean amount (it could be difficulty or something else). I doubt "tremendous work" is regularly used though.

Answer (score 1):

The two definitions from the Oxford dictionary should answer your question:

> **[tremendous](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tremendous)** (adj): 1. Very great in amount, scale, or intensity. 1.1 (informal) Extremely good or impressive; excellent.

Your first sentence relies on the first definition, while your second sentence relies on the second definition.

Interestingly enough, I would have said definition 1 was the more "informal" of the two, but perhaps that's my personal experience.  The [etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/word/tremendous) is:

> from Latin *tremendus* "fearful, to be dreaded, terrible," literally "to be trembled at".

so it would seem definition 1 is closer to the word's origin, i.e. that I have so much work I *tremble* to think about having to do it all.

Answer (score 0):

The two sentences mean different things.

If I want to compute by hand the square root of 3, to 1 million decimal places, then I have a tremendous amount of work to do.(But I can do it: it is a lot of drudgery).

If I want to prove the continuum hypothesis (a famously unproved conjecture in mathematics) I have tremendous work to do (which is so tremendous that I may not even be able to do it).